# Real analysis: inequality on minimum points

Tags: inequality, self-learning

Let $f,g$ be two real functions. I wonder if the following holds true:
$$\lvert\arg \min_x f(x)-\arg \min_x g(x)\rvert\leq \arg\min_x\lvert f(x)-g(x) \rvert.$$

Do you have any conclusion about it? Are there related results on this?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Should that really be an arg min?  If so, then the answer is clearly no

Comment: @Omnomnomnom How does it make sense?

Comment: @pigeon I don't understand your question

Comment: Isn't $\mathrm{arg} \min f$ the set on which $f$ reachs its minimum or am I missing something?

Comment: @pigeon if the minimizer is unique then arg min is the specific element

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I just say the answer is "no", then that's really misleading as you might think that inequality makes sense in general when it doesn't.
Actually $\mathrm{arg} \min\,f$ is a set, and the inequality, as it is, doesn't make much sense. Only if we assume ALL those functions reach their min at one single point then we can make some sense of it, by identifying  arg$\min\, f$ with number it contains. It's still wrong though, as the following example shows.

Take $f(x)=\cos x$ and $g(x)=\sin x$ in the interval $[0,\pi]$. Then $\mathrm{arg}\, \min f= \pi$ and $\mathrm{arg}\, \min g= 0$ while $\mathrm{arg}\, \min |\cos x - \sin x |= 3\pi/4$